# Sails js installation on ubuntu VPS 16.04?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, sails.js, nvm

I am using on local machine(ubuntu) sails js(0.12.4) with the version :

```
node -v =  v4.5.0, nodejs -v = v4.5.0, npm -v =2.15.9 and sudo npm -v = 3.10.0
```

It is working fine while sailsjs is not getting install on VPS 16.04/14.04 ubuntu server.

When I am trying to install sails latest with command :

```
sudo npm install -g sails
```

It's giving following output :

```
Killed.............] | fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
```

and when I am trying to install with following command :

```
sudo npm install -g sails@0.11.5 or npm install -g sails@0.11.5
```

then it's showing following error message :

```
> sails@0.11.5 preinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/sails
> node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

Sails.js Installation: Checking npm-version successful
npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
npm WARN deprecated native-or-bluebird@1.1.2: 'native-or-bluebird' is deprecated. Please use 'any-promise' instead.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
Killed
```

Please suggest, How will I install sails on ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Thanks !

Comment: It is not even installing with latest versions :
node -v = 6.4.0
nodejs -v = 6.4.0
npm -v = 3.10.3
sudo npm -v = 3.10.3

still showing same error message :

sudo npm install -g sails
Killed.............] - fetchMetadata: verb afterAdd /root/.npm/util-deprecate/1.0.2/package/package.json written

Comment: Are you using any node version manager

Comment: @Akinjide Bankole - I am using nvm

Comment: Thought as much, I will guess you add a .nvmrc to your `touch ~\.nvmrc` folder and then install the latest `node` and `npm` through `nvm`. then edit the `.nvmrc` file and add the node version restart your terminal app and try again.

Comment: Akinjide Bankole - still showing sane error :

sudo npm install -g sails
Killed.............] / fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/request

Comment: Did you try resizing your VM as pointed out by Yash Gupta in the answer ? It solved the problem for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most probably running out of RAM on your VM.

Installation scripts can typically take up large amounts of heap space, which might require 1-2GB of RAM. If your runtime app doesn't require such memory, you can look into shipping node_modules from your dev machine to your vm (or use docker).

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has been downvoted. This is precisely what was happening in my case. I resized the virtual machine, increasing RAM from 512MB to 1GB and it worked like a charm. This should be in fact the accepted answer

Comment: yes.. After increasing size of RAM. It worked.

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If you don't mind, please mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking on the tick mark icon near my answer.